# A doubt from Atiyah's K-Theory

Tags: k-theory

This is a question regarding the following statement on pg 43 of [Atiyah's K-Theory](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/atiyahk.pdf).

> Using our construction of $K$ it follows that, if $X$ is a space, every element of $K(X)$ is of the form $[E]-[F]$, where $E,F$ are vector bundles over $X$.

I don't understand this statement. $K(X)$ is the group generated from the elements of $X$. How are $[E]$ and $[F]$, or even $[E]-[F]$, elements of $X$?

Comment: Reread the previous paragraph.

Comment: $K(X)=K(Vect(X))$, see the second to last paragraph on page 43.

Comment: @EricWofsey- Ah Thanks. I thought Vect(X) meant the vector space generated by the elements of $X$. I guess it means the set of semigroup of vector bundles on $X$...?